# Сбились драйвера на Debian 10

Tags: linux, debian, драйвер

Я случайно удалил папку /lib/modules/4.19.0... Как восстановить драйвера в полной мере?

Comment: Через apt переустановить пакеты начинающиеся на `linux-`

Answer (score 1):

Если пакет в кеше

```
sudo dpkg -i /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-4.19.*deb
```